# Is there a number that when multiplied by $2$ equals a perfect square, and when multiplied by $3$ equals a perfect square?

Tags: radicals, square-numbers

I am wondering if there is a number $n$ that when multiplied by $2$ and by $3$ equals a perfect square.

$$n\times 3 = k^2$$
$$n\times 2 = m^2$$

where $n$ is a whole number and not equal to $0$

I have tried every whole number up to $1000$, and my theory is that there isn't a number that fits the criteria. If I am wrong, please include the number that works for both, what it multiplies to, and the square roots of the products.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions.

Comment: There isn’t, except 0. Think in terms of the powers of 2 and 3 in the prime factorisation of the number.

Comment: Click in "edited _ minutes ago" to see how I edited your question and try to do better next time.

Comment: Assuming that $n$ is a positive integer $~ > 1, ~$ let the prime factorization of $n$ be given by $$\prod_{i=1}^r (p_i)^{(a_i)}.$$  From this viewpoint, the problem is immediately conquered.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the first equation by 2 and the second by 3 to get

$6n = 2k^2=3m^2$.

There are an odd number of powers of 2 on the left side
and an even number on the right,
a contradiction.

Note that this works for
$np=k^2, nq=m^2$
where $p$ and $q$
are distinct primes.

It can be generalized further,
but that is left as an exercise.